# Nuxt 3: Pinia: why is my mutating my state destorting the entire array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

here lies my code

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const DB_CART = defineStore("CART", {
    state: () => ({
        CART: [
            {
                $id: "62616ffc6d13e2a9eb04",
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                $id: "6261711719aa15827836",
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                $id: "6275c020740fbd04db50",
                quantity: 1
            }
        ],
    }),
    actions: {
        // INCREMENT PRODUCT QUANTITY IN CART
        incrementCartQuantity(id) {
            const cartItem = this.CART.find(item => item.$id = id);
            cartItem.quantity++;
        },
        // DECREMENT PRODUCT QUANTITY IN CART
        decrementCartQuantity(id) {
            const cartItem = this.CART.find(item => item.$id = id);
            if (cartItem.quantity === 1) return
            cartItem.quantity--;
        },
        // ADD PRODUCT TO CART
        addToCart(item) {
            this.CART.push(item)
        }
    },
    persist: true
})
```

I'd like to understand why when I increment or decrement a cart item starting from the second in the array, the array rearranges.

```js
incrementCartQuantity(id) {
   const cartItem = this.CART.find(item => item.$id = id);
   cartItem.quantity++;

   console.log(this.CART) /*EXPECTED OUTPUT
    [
            {
                $id: "62616ffc6d13e2a9eb04",
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                $id: "6261711719aa15827836",
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                $id: "6275c020740fbd04db50",
                quantity: 1
            }
        ]
  *//*RETURED OUTPUT
    [
            { $id: "6261711719aa15827836", quantity: 2 },
            { $id: "6261711719aa15827836", quantity: 1 }, INCREMENTED OBJECT
            { $id: "6275c020740fbd04db50", quantity: 1 }
        ]
  */
 },
```

in my Vue component, on incrementCartItem, I find out that the entire array kind of shuffles and pops out the one at the top, and replaces it with the item which is being mutated
I don't think the array should be affected in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `find` method is doing an *assignment* "**=**" instead of a *comparison* "**===**".

Replace

```js
  this.CART.find(item => item.$id = id);
```

with

```js
  this.CART.find(item => item.$id === id);
```

in both cart methods.

Your `find` assigns the searched `id` to the first item's `$id`, every time it runs.

Comment: The first solution returned an error, but the second one works, works in incrementing the quantity, but my issue is incrementing the quantity of any object apart from the first, the array would shuffle itself, and duplicate that object, remove the object at the very top and replacing it with the duplicate, and only the quantity of the duplicate will be incremented.

Comment: I updated my answer, after testing your code. See it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pinia-vue-3-demo-forked-158gwi?file=/src/stores/cart.js).

Comment: I understand, while I was doing just what you suggested I found out the error, the .find and even .findIndex method you adviced, I failed to triple the equals to sign, thus the error.

Comment: It does work, I'm the one who failed to copy it correctly